# How do I make my JDK available to Ubuntu when using WSL?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to learn Kafka and started to read [this book](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-the-definitive-guide/) (you can download it and read too if you want, it's free). One of the first steps the authors suggest is installing Zookeeper. In line with their advice, I installed WSL and successfully executed some commands to do that (see p. 18), but then some issue with JDK popped up. I had it installed in the `C:\Program Files\Java\JDK\jdk-17.0.2+8` directory before. Here's what I tried:

```
jorejoh@LAPTOP-CKP86E2O:/mnt/c$ export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program Files/Java/JDK/jdk-17.0.2+8"
jorejoh@LAPTOP-CKP86E2O:/mnt/c$ cd /
jorejoh@LAPTOP-CKP86E2O:/$ /usr/local/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh start
Error: JAVA_HOME is not set and java could not be found in PATH.
```

and this

```
jorejoh@LAPTOP-CKP86E2O:/$ export JAVA_HOME="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Java/JDK/jdk-17.0.2+8"
jorejoh@LAPTOP-CKP86E2O:/$ export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
jorejoh@LAPTOP-CKP86E2O:/$ java -version
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless  # version 11.0.18+10-0ubuntu1~22.04, or
sudo apt install default-jre              # version 2:1.11-72build2
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless  # version 17.0.6+10-0ubuntu1~22.04
sudo apt install openjdk-18-jre-headless  # version 18.0.2+9-2~22.04
sudo apt install openjdk-19-jre-headless  # version 19.0.2+7-0ubuntu3~22.04
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless   # version 8u362-ga-0ubuntu1~22.04
```

Should I really install a JDK a second time, this time for Ubuntu? How do I make my JDK available to it and execute the script?

I did try to install it a second time. The result:

```
jorejoh@LAPTOP-CKP86E2O:/$ sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre-headless
[sudo] password for jorejoh:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openjdk-17-jre-headless
```

Should I have adjusted the proposed command somehow?

Comment: Afaicr you can't. You need to install a Linux jdk

Comment: Ok. That's good but I'm not quite sure whether everything's all right for you now ...

Comment: That edit should be added _as an answer_. Answers are not allowed in questions.

Comment: Even if you could hack in the jdk from your windows world, I wouldn't. You're asking for any number of issue. You can literally download it direct and install - even without apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

```
sudo apt update
```

before trying to install a second JDK (g00se suggested I had to) helped. It was ChatGPT's advice. If you need to know where the JDK is installed, try (also GPT's idea)

```
update-alternatives --list java
```

With that information, you should be able to register that `JAVA_HOME` thing. In my case, it was

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
```

I hope it helps somebody one day